# cakephp 2.5.1: catching misspelled function calls

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have an API wirtten and gave out instructions how to us it.
For example to test the login you can call `/api/login`

Now I see in the logs, that someone keeps calling `/API/LOGIN` and gets an error 500.

Is there somehow a way, to catch such errors ONLY when calling `/api/` controller functions?
In that case, I would like to send back a response like `Error. Wrong function call`.
I do not want to send this in general when a error 500 happens. Really only when `/api/` related.

The error which gets reported belongs to the fact that I am calling in `AppController::beforeFilter()` a function like

```
$this->Api->check($username)
```

And I get this error when debug=2

```
Call to a member function check() on a non-object
```

When I call `/api/login/` the functions works perfect.

I look forward for any tips! Thanks!

Comment: See in your code, have you included the `Api` class in AppController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing isn't the casing of the action (in PHP method names are case insensitive), but the casing of the controller. It won't find `APIController` and therefore throw an missing controller exception. Your `AppController` is then being invoked as it is being extended by `CakeErrorController` which is used on errors.

I can only assume that `$this->Api` refers to a model, and since the actual controller is `CakeErrorController`, that model of course isn't being loaded, hence the non-object error.

There are various ways to solve this problem, personally I'd probably hook in to the `Dispatcher.beforeDispatch` event and throw an exception or define an appropriate response if necessary, something like this:

```
// app/Config/bootstrap.php

App::uses('CakeEvent', 'Event');
App::uses('CakeEventManager', 'Event');

CakeEventManager::instance()->attach(
    function(CakeEvent $event) {
        $controller = $event->data['request']->params['controller'];
        $action = $event->data['request']->params['action'];

        if(strtolower($controller) === 'api') {
            $response = $event->data['response'];

            if($controller !== 'api') {
                $response->statusCode('403');
                $response->body('Invalid controller message');
                return $response;
            }

            if(strtolower($action) !== $action) {
                $response->statusCode('403');
                $response->body('Invalid action method');
                return $response;
            }
        }
    },
    'Dispatcher.beforeDispatch',
    array('priority' => 11)
);
```

This would enforce using lowercase for the controller and the action in case the `api` controller is being targeted.

However as already mentioned, method names are case insensitive, so forcing lowercase for actions isn't necessary from a technical point of view. Anyways, it's just an example...